# Tukey-Test Grouping and plotting in SciPy

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, scipy, anova

I'm trying to plot results from a Tukey test, but I am struggling with putting data into groups based on a P-Value. [This is the equivalent in R](http://www.r-graph-gallery.com/84-tukey-test/) which I am trying to replicate. I have been using the SciPy one-way ANOVA tests and the Tukey test statsmodel but can't get these groups done in the same way.

Any help is greatly appreciated

I've also just found this [another example in R of what I want to do in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771516/is-there-a-function-to-add-aov-post-hoc-testing-results-to-ggplot2-boxplot)

Comment: Is there a general rule how to assign "mixed" membership like the `a,b` in the second link? (I tried to do some grouping in the statsmodels sandbox a long time ago, but then gave up because there is no grouping that partitions the groups. A is not significantly different from B, B is not significantly different from C. But A and C are significantly different. So there is no transitivity.)

Comment: The R package has the reference for the letter assignment: Piepho, Hans-Peter (2004) "An Algorithm for a Letter-Based Representation of All-Pairwise Comparisons"

Comment: I was inspired by BrianM to produce my own version using the same paper as the source for the method. My method can also be used with scikit_posthocs and includes a monte carlo optimisation step to remove further unnecessary letters; described as a 'sweep' in the paper. <a> https://github.com/PhilPlantMan/Python-pairwise-comparison-letter-generator

Comment: This is in Python [link](https://www.statology.org/tukey-test-python/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been struggling to do the same thing.  I found a paper that tells you how to code the letters.
Hans-Peter Piepho (2004) An Algorithm for a Letter-Based Representation of All-Pairwise Comparisons, Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics, 13:2, 456-466, DOI: 10.1198/1061860043515

Doing the coding was a little tricky as you need to check and replicate columns and then combine columns.  I tried to add some comments to the colde.  I figured out a method where you can run tukeyhsd and then from the results compute the letters.  It should be possible to turn this into a function. Or hopefully part of tukeyhsd.  My data is not posted but it is a column of data and then a column describing the groups.  The groups for me are the five boroughs of NYC. You can also just change the comments and use random data the first time.

```
# Read data.  Comment out the next ones to use random data.  
df=pd.read_excel('anova_test.xlsx')
#n=1000
#df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Groups','Data'],index=np.arange(n))
#df['Groups']=np.random.randint(1, 4,size=n)
#df['Data']=df['Groups']*np.random.random_sample(size=n)


# define columns for data and then grouping
col_to_group='Groups'
col_for_data='Data'

#Now take teh data and regroup for anova
samples = [cols[1] for cols in df.groupby(col_to_group)[col_for_data]]    #I am not sure how this works but it makes an numpy array for each group 
f_val, p_val = stats.f_oneway(*samples)  # I am not sure what this star does but this passes all the numpy arrays correctly
#print('F value: {:.3f}, p value: {:.3f}\n'.format(f_val, p_val))

# this if statement can be uncommmented if you don't won't to go furhter with out p<0.05
#if p_val<0.05:    #If the p value is less than 0.05 it then does the tukey
mod = MultiComparison(df[col_for_data], df[col_to_group])
thsd=mod.tukeyhsd()
#print(mod.tukeyhsd())

#this is a function to do Piepho method.  AN Alogrithm for a letter based representation of al-pairwise comparisons.  
tot=len(thsd.groupsunique)
#make an empty dataframe that is a square matrix of size of the groups. #set first column to 1
df_ltr=pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=np.arange(tot),columns=np.arange(tot))
df_ltr.iloc[:,0]=1
count=0
df_nms = pd.DataFrame('', index=np.arange(tot), columns=['names'])  # I make a dummy dataframe to put axis labels into.  sd stands for signifcant difference

for i in np.arange(tot):   #I loop through and make all pairwise comparisons. 
    for j in np.arange(i+1,tot):
        #print('i=',i,'j=',j,thsd.reject[count])
        if thsd.reject[count]==True:
            for cn in np.arange(tot):
                if df_ltr.iloc[i,cn]==1 and df_ltr.iloc[j,cn]==1: #If the column contains both i and j shift and duplicat
                    df_ltr=pd.concat([df_ltr.iloc[:,:cn+1],df_ltr.iloc[:,cn+1:].T.shift().T],axis=1)
                    df_ltr.iloc[:,cn+1]=df_ltr.iloc[:,cn]
                    df_ltr.iloc[i,cn]=0
                    df_ltr.iloc[j,cn+1]=0
                #Now we need to check all columns for abosortpion.
                for cleft in np.arange(len(df_ltr.columns)-1):
                    for cright in np.arange(cleft+1,len(df_ltr.columns)):
                        if (df_ltr.iloc[:,cleft].isna()).all()==False and (df_ltr.iloc[:,cright].isna()).all()==False: 
                            if (df_ltr.iloc[:,cleft]>=df_ltr.iloc[:,cright]).all()==True:  
                                df_ltr.iloc[:,cright]=0
                                df_ltr=pd.concat([df_ltr.iloc[:,:cright],df_ltr.iloc[:,cright:].T.shift(-1).T],axis=1)
                            if (df_ltr.iloc[:,cleft]<=df_ltr.iloc[:,cright]).all()==True:
                                df_ltr.iloc[:,cleft]=0
                                df_ltr=pd.concat([df_ltr.iloc[:,:cleft],df_ltr.iloc[:,cleft:].T.shift(-1).T],axis=1)

        count+=1

#I sort so that the first column becomes A        
df_ltr=df_ltr.sort_values(by=list(df_ltr.columns),axis=1,ascending=False)

# I assign letters to each column
for cn in np.arange(len(df_ltr.columns)):
    df_ltr.iloc[:,cn]=df_ltr.iloc[:,cn].replace(1,chr(97+cn)) 
    df_ltr.iloc[:,cn]=df_ltr.iloc[:,cn].replace(0,'')
    df_ltr.iloc[:,cn]=df_ltr.iloc[:,cn].replace(np.nan,'') 

#I put all the letters into one string
df_ltr=df_ltr.astype(str)
df_ltr.sum(axis=1)
#print(df_ltr)
#print('\n')
#print(df_ltr.sum(axis=1))

#Now to plot like R with a violing plot
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
df.boxplot(column=col_for_data, by=col_to_group,ax=ax,fontsize=16,showmeans=True
                    ,boxprops=dict(linewidth=2.0),whiskerprops=dict(linewidth=2.0))  #This makes the boxplot

ax.set_ylim([-10,20])

grps=pd.unique(df[col_to_group].values)   #Finds the group names
grps.sort() # This is critical!  Puts the groups in alphabeical order to make it match the plotting

props=dict(facecolor='white',alpha=1)
for i,grp in enumerate(grps):   #I loop through the groups to make the scatters and figure out the axis labels. 

    x = np.random.normal(i+1, 0.15, size=len(df[df[col_to_group]==grp][col_for_data]))
    ax.scatter(x,df[df[col_to_group]==grp][col_for_data],alpha=0.5,s=2)
    name="{}\navg={:0.2f}\n(n={})".format(grp
                            ,df[df[col_to_group]==grp][col_for_data].mean()
                            ,df[df[col_to_group]==grp][col_for_data].count())
    df_nms['names'][i]=name 
    ax.text(i+1,ax.get_ylim()[1]*1.1,df_ltr.sum(axis=1)[i],fontsize=10,verticalalignment='top',horizontalalignment='center',bbox=props)


ax.set_xticklabels(df_nms['names'],rotation=0,fontsize=10)
ax.set_title('')
fig.suptitle('')

fig.savefig('anovatest.jpg',dpi=600,bbox_inches='tight')
```

[Results showing the letters above plots using the tukeyhsd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gksxT.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that returns letter labels if you have a symmetric matrix of p-values from a Tukey test:

```
import numpy as np

def tukeyLetters(pp, means=None, alpha=0.05):
    '''TUKEYLETTERS - Produce list of group labels for TukeyHSD
    letters = TUKEYLETTERS(pp), where PP is a symmetric matrix of 
    probabilities from a Tukey test, returns alphabetic labels
    for each group to indicate clustering. PP may also be a vector
    from PAIRWISE_TUKEYHSD.
    Optional argument MEANS specifies group means, which is used for
    ordering the letters. ("a" gets assigned to the group with lowest
    mean.) Without this argument, ordering is arbitrary.
    Optional argument ALPHA specifies cutoff for treating groups as
    part of the same cluster.'''

    if len(pp.shape)==1:
        # vector
        G = int(3 + np.sqrt(9 - 4*(2-len(pp))))//2
        ppp = .5*np.eye(G)
        ppp[np.triu_indices(G,1)] = pp    
        pp = ppp + ppp.T
    conn = pp>alpha
    G = len(conn)
    if np.all(conn):
        return ['a' for g in range(G)]
    conns = []
    for g1 in range(G):
        for g2 in range(g1+1,G):
            if conn[g1,g2]:
                conns.append((g1,g2))

    letters = [ [] for g in range(G) ]
    nextletter = 0
    for g in range(G):
        if np.sum(conn[g,:])==1:
            letters[g].append(nextletter)
            nextletter += 1
    while len(conns):
        grp = set(conns.pop(0))
        for g in range(G):
            if all(conn[g, np.sort(list(grp))]):
                grp.add(g)
        for g in grp:
            letters[g].append(nextletter)
        for g in grp:
            for h in grp:
                if (g,h) in conns:
                    conns.remove((g,h))
        nextletter += 1

    if means is None:
        means = np.arange(G)
    means = np.array(means)
    groupmeans = []
    for k in range(nextletter):
        ingroup = [g for g in range(G) if k in letters[g]]
        groupmeans.append(means[np.array(ingroup)].mean())
    ordr = np.empty(nextletter, int)
    ordr[np.argsort(groupmeans)] = np.arange(nextletter)
    result = []
    for ltr in letters:
        lst = [chr(97 + ordr[x]) for x in ltr]
        lst.sort()
        result.append(''.join(lst))
    return result
```

To make that concrete, here is a full example:

```
from statsmodels.stats.multicomp import pairwise_tukeyhsd

data  = [ 1,2,2,1,4,5,4,5,7,8,7,8,1,3,4,5 ]
group = [ 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3 ]
tuk = pairwise_tukeyhsd(data, group) 
letters = tukeyLetters(tuk.pvalues)
```

This will result in `letters` containing `['a', 'c', 'b', 'ac']`